# Seeking help to write a PHP preg_replace pattern to replace inconsistent values

Tags: php, preg-replace

In JSON string I need to replace inconsistent values in multiple instances

**String format to replace within each instance**

inconsistent value *252/2022/08* to be replaced with consistent value ***178/2023/03***

```
{"url":"/wp-content/uploads/sites/252/2022/08/banner-rental.jpg",
```

Another instance may be. Note the difference with `06`

```
{"url":"/wp-content/uploads/sites/252/2022/06/banner-swx.jpg",
```

The replacement value is passed by WordPress `wp_upload_dir()['url']` which is `/wp-content/uploads/sites/178/2023/03` stored in var `$replace`

**method tried**

```php
preg_replace('#/wp-content/uploads/sites/(.*?)/#i',$replace,$jsondata);
```

The result is close but of course the stop point is at the first slash after `sites/`. I can't define the process to find and set the last slash as the end point.

```
{"url":"/wp-content/uploads/sites/178/2023/032022/06/banner-swx.jpg",
```

**How can I find and set the last slash before the image name, as the ending point for the search?**

Comment: You should use a pattern, not `.*`. It is always a bad date? Maybe https://regex101.com/r/MOAiFK/1 works

Comment: Literally just drop the `?` from the pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This pattern returned the correct result, don't know why but it works as desired.

```php
$data = '{"url":"/wp-content/uploads/sites/252/2022/06/banner-swx.jpg","url":"/wp-content/uploads/sites/252/2022/09/banner-rental.jpg"}';
$replace = wp_upload_dir()['url'];
preg_replace('#/wp-content/uploads/sites/(.*?)[^/]{4}[/$][^/]{2}#i',$replace,$data);
```

Comment: Provided regex 17 hours didn't work? You've written capture everything until a non `/` then look for another non `.`, then look for another non `.` 4 more times, then a `/` or `$` (not sure why you're looking for a `$`). then 2 more times a non `/`. `[^/][^/][^/][^/]` is the same as `[^/]{4}` but even that is a very loose regex. Should realllly define a pattern.

Comment: I did **not** follow the link you posted. If you have or had a solution, post it as an answer so others can benefit, and if it does what I need, I'll check it as accepted.

Comment: The link shows everything, click it. Or if by didn't follow you meant understand what the pages is showing.. the top is the regex, middle is your string, bottom is substitution. You haven't provided enough details to define a good regex so I can't post an answer. My best guess is above.

Comment: @user3783243 I did not click the link before and still haven't. Not sure how much more detail you need. That you posted a solution at another site suggests you understand the inquiry. Just post the answer at this website so others can gain from your knowledge.

Comment: Is there a pattern? Is `/wp-content/uploads/sites/#/#/$/*.*` consistent? Can numbers vary, extension be optional, etc? You only provided 1 example.